# Where to request specific feedback about Vim tweaks

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to, for example, start a question to get a better feel for how advanced LAMP programmers tweak vim, specifically to highlight both PHP code and MySQL code. Is this a valid question to ask here, and if so where would I ask it?

Comment: Your question doesn't have to be limited to LAMP... People use PHP and MYSQL with vim for many reasons.  You might want to look into syntax hilighting in vim.  I do not think that this question is suited for out [so] format.  It is a question about the usage of an (awesome) program  as opposed to a programming question... http://www.vim.org/ - is the place you want to look.

Comment: @Lix How about Super User?

Comment: @jae - well actually after looking at the [vim tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) there seems to be many questions on vim... However most of those are about specific tasks as opposed to "how to turn on syntax highlighting"...  [SU] might be a better choice over [so], however **IMO**  this question might be too simplistic to help anyone in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about a specific tweak?  Because if you are, your question is on-topic at Stack Overflow (being a programming tool question).

If you're asking for a ["list of things"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128561/102937) (as in "What are the different ways you tweak Vim), your question is off-topic everywhere.

Comment: unfortunately I would be looking for a list. However, the only reason I would do so is b/c I have exhausted all other possibilities. I have googled to death 'command line mysql beautifiers' and `vim php mysql`.

Comment: here is the question I desperately want answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684806/real-sql-syntax-highlighting-in-php-scripts-with-vim